# ASP.NET MVC Html.ActionLink Hover Styling

Tags: css, asp.net

Is it possible to style the hover effect of my Login Partial ActionLinks so they don't include any text decoration and change to a different color than blue. I assume it should be something along the lines of ":hover:text-decoration:none"

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", style = "font-size:12px; font-weight:800; letter-spacing:1px; text-transform:uppercase;" })</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li #loginLink:hover{ 
    color:red!important;
     text-decoration:none!important;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you would use `!important` in this case. Styling without `!important` would work just as fine

Comment: I've inserted it that would be ineffective if it's featured in another class.

Comment: Without the !important the text didn't appear red on hover in my view. To apply to other similar ActionLinks should I target the actionName or linkText?